Streaming large dataset to child process (as JSON)
I'm trying to send a large amount of data that is stored in memory to a child process. Specifically I have a large dataset represented as JSON in Node.js which I want to send to a child process I am spawning (Deno).
This is the most basic attempt I've made:
const deno = spawn('deno', ['run', '--allow-all', '--unstable-bare-node-builtins', '--unstable-sloppy-imports', `--allow-read=${cwd}`, filename], {
    stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'],
    cwd,
    env: {
        PATH: process.env.PATH,
        DENO_NO_PACKAGE_JSON: '1'
    }
});

const payload = JSON.stringify({
    some: 'data'
});

deno.stdin.write(payload);

However I've also tried observing the drain event while writing:
// Recursive function to write a chunk to the child process.
const writeChunk = async (chunk: string) => {
    const written = deno.stdin.write(chunk);

    if (!written) {
        // Wait for drain if necessary
        await new Promise((resolve) => deno.stdin.once('drain', resolve));
        return writeChunk(chunk);
    }
};

This seemed to result in more data but still I am clearly missing chunks of the JSON or they are out of order because I cannot successfully parse it in the Deno process.
Additionally I tried just piping the output of cat dataset.json but Deno complains with an error ENOTTY: Not a Typewriter. Upon googling and "ChatGPTing" this I couldn't resolve it.

FYI: I'm trying to use STDIN because it seems like the most efficient way to transfer this data without it leaving memory. Writing to a disk is my last resort as that would be much slower I imagine.

And so I'm not sure if it's the way I'm sending the data over STDIN or how i'm receiving it but I must be doing something wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Is there just a better way to do this?

Although I'm not sure I fully understand everything you've written in the question… it seems like you're asking for an example showing how to pipe a stream of JSON data from a Node.js process to a Deno child process — and parse that data in the Deno process (…and perhaps pipe data back and read it in Node).
Below I put together a minimal, reproducible example that you can use as a model. It includes types and comments explaining each step.
Additionally, here are some APIs used in the Node.js code that might not already be familiar:

Blob
Response
ReadableStream
WritableStream
stream.Writable.toWeb(streamWritable)


Files:
./package.json:
{
  "name": "so-78915710",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "check:types": "tsc --noEmit",
    "compile": "tsc",
    "test": "node --test dist/test.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=20.17.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^22.5.0",
    "typescript": "^5.5.4"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}

./tsconfig.json:
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",

  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,

    "removeComments": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,

    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    "target": "ES2022",
    "lib": ["ESNext"],

    "isolatedDeclarations": true,
    "declaration": true,

    "outDir": "./dist"
  },

  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["./src/stdio_json_buffer_echo.ts"]
}

./src/example.ts:
import { type SpawnOptionsWithoutStdio, spawn } from "node:child_process";
import { Writable } from "node:stream";

type JsonValue =
  | boolean
  | number
  | null
  | string
  | JsonValue[]
  | { [key: string]: JsonValue | undefined };

async function example(): Promise<JsonValue> {
  const env: NodeJS.ProcessEnv = {
    // Shown in the code in your question, but unused in this example:
    // PATH: process.env.PATH,
    DENO_NO_PACKAGE_JSON: "1",
  };

  const spawnOptions: SpawnOptionsWithoutStdio = {
    // cwd: process.cwd(), // Default
    env,
    // stdio: ["pipe", "pipe", "pipe"], // Default
  };

  const denoModuleFilePath = import.meta.resolve(
    "../src/stdio_json_buffer_echo.ts",
  );

  const denoArgs = ["run", denoModuleFilePath] satisfies readonly string[];
  using childProcess = spawn("deno", denoArgs, spawnOptions);

  // The data in memory that can be serialized as JSON
  const serializable = { foo: "bar" };

  // A (WHATWG standard) ReadableStream representing a copy of that data serialized as JSON
  const jsonByteStream = new Blob([JSON.stringify(serializable)]).stream();

  // Convert the stdin of the child process to a (WHATWG standard) WritableStream
  const writableStream = Writable.toWeb(childProcess.stdin);

  // Wait for both of the following async operations to complete (read + write),
  // and assign the resolved value from the first operation to a varaible:
  const [parsed] = await Promise.all([
    // Collect the byte stream from the child process and parse as JSON
    new Response(childProcess.stdout).json() as Promise<JsonValue>,
    // Write the JSON byte stream to the stdin of the child process
    jsonByteStream.pipeTo(writableStream),
  ] as const);

  return parsed;
}

export { example, type JsonValue };

./src/stdio_json_buffer_echo.ts (this is the module that will run in Deno):
// Collect the byte stream and parse as JSON
const parsed = await new Response(Deno.stdin.readable).json();

// Re-serialize…
const json = JSON.stringify(parsed);

// …and emit to stdout
await new Blob([json]).stream().pipeTo(Deno.stdout.writable);

./src/test.ts:
import { deepEqual as assertDeepEqual } from "node:assert/strict";
import { test } from "node:test";

import { example } from "./example.js";

test("deno child process returns expected JSON data", async () => {
  const expected = { foo: "bar" };
  const actual = await example();
  assertDeepEqual(actual, expected);
});

Software versions:
% node --version
v20.17.0

% npm --version
10.8.2

% deno --version
deno 1.46.1 (stable, release, aarch64-apple-darwin)
v8 12.9.202.2-rusty
typescript 5.5.2

Running the example test:
% npm install

added 3 packages, and audited 4 packages in 431ms

found 0 vulnerabilities

% npm run compile && npm run test

> so-78915710@0.1.0 compile
> tsc


> so-78915710@0.1.0 test
> node --test dist/test.js

✔ deno child process returns expected JSON data (21.365625ms)
ℹ tests 1
ℹ suites 0
ℹ pass 1
ℹ fail 0
ℹ cancelled 0
ℹ skipped 0
ℹ todo 0
ℹ duration_ms 53.168541


Thank you for this example! I set this up locally and it worked just fine even with a reasonably sized dataset. So I tried porting this over to my code and in that process I discovered that I was only encountering this issue when importing a specific npm package in the Deno environment.
This honestly seems like a bug in Deno's compatibility with npm packages and node. I'm going to open an issue there but do you happen to have any idea why importing a package in Deno with the npm: specifier would break reading from stdin?

^ @Jaron That would depend on the specific package… but the dependency is probably manipulating stdin. You'd have to audit the dependency's source code to make a determination.

Yea I'm going to take a cursory look at it. Unfortunately its a private package but I think it's one of the dependencies that is the problem. Thank you for your help!
